# How can I avoid having a separate custom TypeDescriptorProvider for each of my classes?

Tags: c#, typedescriptor, customtypedescriptor, typedescriptionprovider

I've added functionality to my project that allows the users to add their own custom properties to objects. I've created my own custom **TypeDescriptor**, **PropertyDescriptor** and **TypeDescriptorProviders** etc.. etc.. to do this.

Here's my problem. Right now I have it all working, but had to create a separate **TypeDescriptionProvider** for each object object type that can have the custom properties. Here's what my **TypeDescriptionProviders** look like

```
//type AClass Custom Provider
class AClassTypeProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    private static TypeDescriptionProvider defaultTypeProvider = TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(AClass));

    public AClassTypeProvider (): base(defaultTypeProvider)
    {

    }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        ICustomTypeDescriptor defaultDescriptor = base.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance);

        //returns a custom type descriptor based on a UserPropertyHostType enum value, and the default descriptor
        return new InfCustomTypeDescriptor(UserPropertyHostType.SiteRegion, defaultDescriptor);
    }
}


//type BClass Custom Provider
class BClassTypeProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    private static TypeDescriptionProvider defaultTypeProvider =   TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(BClass));

    public BClassTypeProvider (): base(defaultTypeProvider)
    {

    }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        ICustomTypeDescriptor defaultDescriptor = base.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance);

        //returns a custom type descriptor based on a UserPropertyHostType enum value, and the default descriptor
        return new InfCustomTypeDescriptor(UserPropertyHostType.Building, defaultDescriptor);
    }
}
```

So each of my custom **TypeDescriptionProviders** calls the **base(TypeDescriptionProvider parent)** base constructor by passing it the default **TypeDescriptionProvider** of a specific type.

The **GetTypeDescriptor()** method calls **base.GetTypeDescriptor()** to get the default descriptor which is then used by my custom type descriptor to add on the custom properties.

Is there some way to combine these into a single generic custom **TypeDescriptionProvider** that has the same functionality, but is not tied to a specific type? Can I skip providing the parent **TypeDescriptionProvider** in the constructor but later set it in the **GetTypeDescriptor()** method when I know specifically what type of object is being queried? Or is there some other way of getting the default descriptor of a type other then calling the **base.GetTypeDescriptor(Type t,object ins)** method?

Comment: Here's an easy mnemonic for spelling "separate": "A rat". If you don't see "a rat" in the word, you didn't spell it right.

Comment: Thanks, that one always gets me.

Comment: @Eric: me too, until my brother taught me the mnemonic.

Answer (score 2):

This generic class should do what you want :

```
class CustomTypeProvider<T> : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    private static TypeDescriptionProvider defaultTypeProvider = TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(T));

    public CustomTypeProvider(): base(defaultTypeProvider)
    {

    }

    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
    {
        ICustomTypeDescriptor defaultDescriptor = base.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance);

        //returns a custom type descriptor based on a UserPropertyHostType enum value, and the default descriptor
        return new InfCustomTypeDescriptor(UserPropertyHostType.SiteRegion, defaultDescriptor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have handled this in the past by using a generic type:

```
public class MyTypeDescriptionProvider<T> : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
  public MyTypeDescriptionProvider()
    : base(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(typeof(T)))
  {
  }
}
```

I am pretty sure you could handle it similarly in a non-generic type by passing the type as a constructor parameter:

```
public class MyTypeDescriptionProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
  public MyTypeDescriptionProvider(Type t)
    : base(TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(t))
  {
  }
}
```

This is probably preferable if you don't need to use the type within the provider -- haven't tested it though.

Then when using this provider, classes are registered along the lines of:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new MyTypeDescriptionProvider<ClassA>(), typeof(ClassA));
TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(new MyTypeDescriptionProvider<ClassB>(), typeof(ClassB));
```

etc.

Comment: Unfortunately the non-generic solution doesn't work and will throw a `MissingMethodException`: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.